# Why is my TFS build not building the needed libraries?

Tags: git, visual-studio, tfs

I am working with configuring a TFS 2015 build definition. When I do a build of the local solution, all the needed libraries and references get built in my bin path but when the build runs on the build agent I'm missing a bunch of the references. I have been adjusting the copy local settings and removing/re-adding the references but have had no luck with making the build definition create all the required ones.

If I edit one of the projects in my solution I'm trying to build here's an example of what I have:

```
<Reference Include="WebArchitecture.Services.Common">
     <HintPath>..\..\..\Libraries\WebArchitecture.Services.Common.dll</HintPath>
     <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
```

Is this private tag causing the references to not be built on the build server or is it something else? The solution is located at C:\Users\AKS\Repositories\Git\CUIA\source\ and the libraries are located at C:\Users\AKS\Repositories\Git\CUIA\Libraries.

Adding on additional info based on Patrick's comment:
I believe we're running on XAML. The bin folder was checked into our Git repository so all the needed files should be there.

Comment: Which build system are you using  the old XAML or new Vnext? Moreover,   did your check in bin folder including dlls in source control or copy/deploy them to the build agent? Seems there are not corresponding dlls in the physical folders on the build agent. You need to make sure the environment of build agent as same as local.

Answer (score 0):

First, please double check that you're correctly referencing the dlls using correct relative paths.

Then next step is to make sure the **files are being pulled down** into the build agent/server's workspace. You can verify that by just examining the build folder on the server. If they aren't there then there's probably a problem with the workspace mappings that define the folders to get when beginning a build.

Another way to check is **manually building your solution on the build agent/server**. If the local build on the server is successful, then the issue may related to your build definition settings such as working folder mapping , you'll need some more diagnostic info.

---

**Update:**

Seems your issue is **Bin** folder is not generated in Build Server. If the dlls exists. As a workaround you could use the **CopyDirectory** activity in build process template to copy Bin folder to build machine, please refer to the example in this blog: [TFS Team Build 2010: How to place the build output to a fixed location](http://blog.ehn.nu/2010/09/tfs-team-build-2010-how-to-place-the-build-output-to-a-fixed-location/)

The directory that you specify in the Destination property in **CopyDirectory** activity must already exist. Empty directories or subdirectories are not copied.

Comment: I had it set to use a filepath instead of the TFS server, I did alter it to server in my testing and when I did I checked the artifacts and was still not able to see the bin folder. I should note, I know the bin folder being checked in is bad practice so I removed it. Locally it still builds what it needs, but the server no longer creates a bin folder or the files needed. Would those workspace mappings be something to do with my solution or with the build agent? Other people use the same build agent without a problem, so I'm not sure what to inspect on my own solution to resolve this.

Comment: If others use the same build agent without a problem. There maybe something wrong with your build definition, such as  the workspace mapping as you mentioned. You must make sure your local bin folders are  mapped to server. Moreover, just as you said, check in bin folder is a bad practice which cause some build reference issues such as yours. For now, we often suggest developers try to create their own Nuget package to handle this situation and restore the nuget package on the build server which will also make the environment clean. You could also give a try with this.

Comment: How can I ensure my local bin folders are mapped to the server? Do I need to check in an empty bin folder in my repo for it to be able to place files there?

Comment: @Vistance No, I mean sometimes  the dlls will be automatically excluded by the source control system due to something such as `.gitignore` file. You need to double check whether the dlls are in source control system.]One way is checking the code in GIT repository on the webportal.

Comment: Seems your issue is **Bin** folder is not generated in Build Server. If the dlls exists. As a workaround you could use the **CopyDirectory** activity in build process template to copy Bin folder to build machine, please refer to the example in this blog: http://geekswithblogs.net/jakob/archive/2010/09/01/tfs-team-build-2010-how-to-place-the-build-output.aspx. The directory that you specify in the Destination property in CopyDirectory activity must already exist. Empty directories or subdirectories are not copied.